# How can I add notes to my first slide, which is a full-screen PDF?

Tags: beamer, pdfpages, pgfpages

The first slide in my Beamer presentation is a full-screen PDF which I include using `\includepdf` from the `pdfpages` package. I want to add speaking notes for this first slide using `\note` and to have these notes displayed on my second monitor. I tried the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1]{example-image-a}
\note{This is a note}
\end{document}
```

However, this fails to compile with the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \beamer@shortframetitle 
                                
l.8 \note{This is a note}
```

The problem occurs only when the very first slide in the presentation is produced using `\includepdf`.  Adding notes to `\includepdf` slides later in the presentation works fine.

Short of adding an empty frame to the beginning of the document, how can I best work around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the pdf is included by classical `\includegraphics`, on a costumed `background canvas` beamer template.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \includegraphics[
      width=\paperwidth,
      height=\paperheight,
      keepaspectratio=false,
      % page=1
    ]{example-image-a}%
  }
  \begin{frame}[plain]
  \end{frame}
}

\note{This is a note}
\end{document}
```

[image]